# ancoragem dentro do select option

Tags: php, javascript, html

é possível? já tentei através do A e do value do option mas preciso do value com a informação que puxo do banco se não o formulário não funciona

existe uma maneira de colocar ancoragem no select option???

Comment: Para haver mais chances de alguém te ajudar recomendo que coloque junto com a pergunta o código que está utilizando .

Comment: Ancora pra link ou pra target? Dentro como, em algum option específico? Seria legal você [edit] para deixar claro o que pretende, assim evita o pessoal responder no chute (e aí você vai poder ter um melhor proveito do que for postado).

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é disparar um evento ao selecionar uma opção do select, por exemplo;

```js
//monitora alterações no select "#meu-select"
$(document).on("change", "#meu-select", function(e){
  if($(this).val() == "1"){
    //chama uma função ajax por exemplo que retorna os valores do banco
    //minhaFuncaoAjax()
  }
  
  //voce pode redirecionar para uma pagina com o resultado
  else if($(this).val() == "2"){
    location.href = "https://www.google.com.br"
  }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="meu-select">
  <option>Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1 (chama função ajax)</option>
  <option value="2">Opção 2 (com redirecionamento) </option>
  <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
</select>
```